# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el confirm obtenga el nombre a eliminar dinámicamente y posteriormente lo elimine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo esta tabla

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">            <thead>

                <tr class="text-uppercase">


                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Articulo</th>
                    <th>Contenido</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Usuarios</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Eliminar</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>            <tbody>
                <?php $contador=1; ?>
                @foreach($listaarticulo as $articulo)
                <tr data-identificador="{{$contador}}">

                    <td>{{$articulo->id}}</td>
                    <td data-nombrearticulo="{{$articulo->title}}">{{$articulo->title}}</td>
                    <td>{{$articulo->content}}</td>

                    <td>{{$articulo->categoria->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$articulo->usuario->name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{route('articulos.edit',$articulo->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> EDITAR
</span></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!! Form::open(array('route' =>array('articulos.destroy',$articulo->id),'method'=>'delete')) !!}
                        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash eliminarArticulo" value ="ELIMINAR" >
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </td>


                </tr>
                <?php $contador = $contador + 1 ?>          @endforeach             </tbody>        </table>
```

Lo que quiero es que al pulsar en el boton con la clase  eliminarArticulo, me muestre un confirm diciendo que se va a eliminar el articulo de nombre xx de la tabla seleccionada y posteriormente si dices que si lo elimine.
El problema lo tengo al intentar acceder a esa columna, ya que el contenido es dinamico y no se muy bien como referenciarlo.

He hecho esto pero aun sigo sin conseguirlo

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.eliminarArticulo').click(

            function()
            { 
                var fila =  $(this).parents('tr');
                      var valor= fila.data("identificador");    
                    var articulo = $(this).data("nombrearticulo");
                    if(confirm('seguro que deseas eliminar este Articulo :: '+'  '+articulo+'  '+valor))
                    {
                        return true;        
                    }


            });

})
```

esto me selecciona la columna 2 entera , yo quiero que me seleccione la fila de la columna 2 del boton donde le de yo a eliminar, para obtener el nombre del articulo seleccionado.

Luego si uso el metodo click, me elimina directamente el articulo sin tener en cuenta el confirm, sin embargo si uso el metodo submit, me aparece el confirm pero no me elimina el articulo

Answer (score 1):

Intenta algo así y adaptalo a lo que necesitas

```js
function eliminar(id)
{
    if(confirm('Seguro de eliminar el item: ' + id))
    {
        alert("Eliminado");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Cancelado");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Demo 1</th>
            <th>Accion</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
             <td>Valor 1</td>
             <td><button onclick="eliminar(1)">Eliminar</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Valor 2</td>
             <td><button onclick="eliminar(2)">Eliminar</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Valor 3</td>
             <td><button onclick="eliminar(3)">Eliminar</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Valor 4</td>
             <td><button onclick="eliminar(4)">Eliminar</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Valor 5</td>
             <td><button onclick="eliminar(5)">Eliminar</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Valor 6</td>
             <td><button onclick="eliminar(6)">Eliminar</button></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @UnknDown. No debes insertar enlaces a jsfiddle, en su lugar puedes colocar el código apropiado aquí en el sitio.

Comment: Ok, soy nuevo aquí así que gracias por aclarar :)

Comment: No te preocupes, estamos para ayudarnos :)

Answer (score 0):

Pues tomando como base que tienes datos dinámicos puedes hacer como lo siguiente:

**Javascript Nativo (No Jquery)**

```js
//Aquí voy a simular los elementos dinamicos pensando que ya tienes un elemento <table> en el documento HTML

var data = [{"id":1,"articulo":"a","contenido":"aa","categoria":"aaa","acciones":["ed","el"]},{"id":3,"articulo":"b","contenido":"bb","categoria":"bbb","acciones":["ed"]}]
var a = document.querySelector("#miTabla tbody"); //Buscamos la tabla

if(a != "undefined" || a != "null"){ //Comprabamos que exista la tabla
  if(typeof data === "object"){ //Comprobamos que los datos sean object
    var filas = "";
    for(var b in data){ //Iteramos los datos.
      var c = data[b];
      var editar = (c.acciones["ed"] != "undefined" || c.acciones["ed"] != null) ? "<span class='acciones'>Editar</span> ":""; //Buscamos si tenemos un array con el apuntador ed y asignamos su valor.
      var eliminar = (c.acciones["el"] != "undefined" || c.acciones["el"] != null) ? "<span class='acciones'>Eliminar</span>":""; // Buscamos si tenemos un array con el apuntador el y asignamos su valor
      filas += "<tr><td>"+c.id+"</td><td>"+c.articulo+"</td><td>"+c.contenido+"</td><td>"+c.categoria+"</td><td>"+editar+eliminar+"</td></tr>"; //Construimos las filas con la información del objeto
    }
    a.innerHTML=filas; //Insertamos todas las filas generadas en la tabla
    var acciones = a.querySelectorAll("span.acciones"); //Buscamos todas las acciones por el elemento span y clase .acciones
    if(acciones != "undefined" || acciones != "null"){ //Verificamos que existan
      for(var acc in acciones){ //Iteramos las acciones encontradas
        var acci = acciones[acc]; 
        if(typeof acci == "object"){
         acci.onclick = function (){ //Asignamos el evento Click
        var tipo = this.outerText; //Obtenemos el texto de la acción para saber si editamos o eliminamos
        if(tipo == "Editar"){ //Solo para editar
          var c = confirm("Quieres editar esta fila?"); //Confirmamos si quiere editar
          if(c){ // Hizo click en aceptar...
            alert("Si quiere editar");
          }else{ // Click en cancelar
            alert("no, no quiere editar");
          }
        }else{ // Solo para eliminar
          var c = confirm("estas apunto de eliminar, continuar?"); //Confirmamos si quiere eliminar
        if(c){// Hizo click en aceptar
          var tr = this.offsetParent.parentElement; // Localizamos la Fila
          tr.remove(); //Eliminamos la fila
           }else{ // Hizo click en cancelar.
             alert("No, no quiso eliminar.");
           }
        }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.acciones:hover{
cursor: pointer;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="miTabla">
 <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Articulo</th><th>Contenido</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Acciones</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```